# Memory Leak Debugging in XCode Instruments, iOS

Tags: c#, ios, xcode, xamarin.ios, instruments

I'm using Instrument's Memory Allocation template to find memory leaks in my Application.  I'm seeing some strange results in the Details Panel.  When I find "non-objects" that are clearly memory leaks, and I go to the code that Instruments points me to, it is supposed to highlight code to show me where the leak is happening.  For some reason it's highlighting code incorrectly.  Any ideas why?  I've done build cleans, restarted, etc, but it seems like it's linking to lines of code incorrectly or to old code maybe?  It does seem like it's pointing to the correct class and to the correct general location of the memory leak.

See screenshots below of it highlighting empty lines and even commented code.  I know debugging requires me to put forth effort and I'm not expecting this thing to magically do everything for me, it's just misleading that it's highlighting comments and completely empty lines of code.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is this a Release build or a Debug build?

Comment: It is a Release build

Comment: Can you try a Debug build to see if you get the same incorrect source locations?